Grigio meaning, in Shiras's Children of the Atom
Which Grigio is Paul's guide dog named after? Welles remarks on it in the New Foundations chapter.

For the first fortnight, Dr. Welles made no effort to quiz Stella, but
left her largely to the society of Elsie and Tim, and observed her as
much as he could. Offered her choice of a pet, Stella said that since
all the others were breeding cats she would be content with only one
of her own, and she chose a coal-black, short-haired, green-eyed tom
which she had neutered. She named it Hegai; and Peter Welles had
almost as hard a time tracking down that name as he had in identifying
the Grigio for which Jay's guardian's guide-dog was named. Stella and
Elsie went almost daily to the main library and returned loaded with
volumes. Miss Page privately kept a list of the titles.

Hegai for Stella's tom makes sense as Wiki says he was a Biblical eunuch. And the cat is neutered.

Both of these seem to be religious references.

Hegai from The Book of Esther as the (eunuch) protector of Ahasuerus' harem.


Hegai, who was responsible for the harem, was very much impressed with
her and did his best to make her happy; he ordered a special menu for
her, favored her for the beauty treatments, gave her seven girls from
the palace as her maids, and gave her the most luxurious apartment in
the harem
Esther 2:9-11


Grigio was a famous dog that protected by Saint Don Bosco on his travels.


"Gray", èl Gris', in Piedmontese, was a mysterious dog that
accompanied St. John Bosco for more than thirty years, protecting him
from dangers.
In the 1850s, Don Bosco was the victim of frequent attacks and it was
in those years that this dog began to appear, always protecting the
Saint of Youth.
Don Bosco wrote that he saw Gray for the last time in 1866, then he
mysteriously disappeared.
Don Bosco was asked several times for his opinion on the nature of
that animal and he once replied: "To say that it is an angel would
make us smile, but we cannot even say that it is a common dog."
"Grigio - Gray", the dog who protected Don Bosco


Perfect. Yes, the Catholic slant makes sense. Shiras is into Aquinas, in the book.

P.s. is the profile picture you, or some scifi character?  Or something else?

@Guesttroll - I'm secretly Buffy the Vampire Slayer.

That, along with wondering if David Keith resembles himself.
